# How to apply jquery effect to only one element at a time, not the whole list?

Tags: jquery

I've a CMS which generates a list like following :

```
<div class="span-feed">
<div class="project-thumb"><img src="..." /></div>
<div class="info-overlay"><h1>Something</h1></div>
</div><!--.span-feed-->
```

I wish to hide info-overlay class and make visible only when user hovers on the thumbnail. Its pretty easy to make it happen for a single thumbnail but when there are multiple items in the generated list, the hover effects gets triggered on all the thumbnails, which is logically correct, but I dont want that to happen.
I'm a jQuery noob, kindly suggest me how can I limit the effects to a single thumbnail at a time.
I only want the effect to get triggered on the thumbnail user hovers on.

EDIT: The CMS is generating a ul list as follows:

```
<ul>
<li><div class="span-feed">
<div class="project-thumb"><img src="..." /></div>
<div class="info-overlay"><h1>Something</h1></div>
</div><!--.span-feed--></li>

<li><div class="span-feed">
<div class="project-thumb"><img src="..." /></div>
<div class="info-overlay"><h1>Something</h1></div>
</div><!--.span-feed--></li>

<li><div class="span-feed">
<div class="project-thumb"><img src="..." /></div>
<div class="info-overlay"><h1>Something</h1></div>
</div><!--.span-feed--></li>

</ul>
```

jQuery is as follows:

```
$('.project-thumb').mouseover(function(){
    $('.info-overlay').fadeIn("slow");
});

$('.project-thumb').mouseout(function(){
    $('.info-overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: Thank you @NimChimpsky & @Simon, I've got it working :)

Comment: please show us your javascript so we can find the error.

Comment: Please show the mark-up that correlates to multiple thumbnails. Are they all within the same `.info-overlay` element, or do they appear each in their own parent `.info-overlay`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.project-thumb').hover(function(){
    $(this).next('.info-overlay').fadeIn("slow");
  }, function(){
    $(this).next('.info-overlay').fadeOut();
  });
```

use the hover function with next selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this next, which select the next element that match the selector.

```
$('.project-thumb').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).next('.info-overlay').fadeIn("slow");
});

$('.project-thumb').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).next('.info-overlay').fadeOut();
});
```